# How to replace parameter in Sequelize raw query with user input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

I have a search bar and I want to use the user input to query with Sequelize raw query. What am I missing here and why it is not working?

```
router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    let { term } = req.query;

    db.query(
        'SELECT * FROM locations WHERE code= :term',
        { replacements: term, raw: true, type: QueryTypes.SELECT})
        .then(locations => res.render('locations', { locations }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass an object to replacements : `replacements: { term }`, you were just passing the string `term`, solution:

```
router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
let { term } = req.query;

db.query(
    'SELECT * FROM locations WHERE code= :term',
    { replacements: { term } , raw: true, type: QueryTypes.SELECT})
    .then(locations => res.render('locations', { locations }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

})
```

For Reference an example from docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html

```
await sequelize.query(
  'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE :search_name',
  {
    replacements: { search_name: 'ben%' },
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT
  }
);
```